# Christianity anniversary Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know the anniversary of Christianity’s graduation is coming up on May 29, 2014? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events are a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-led initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: How do our Jehovah's Witness contributors feel about this?

Comment: @Wikis i think we can call it an anniversary i'm going to edit

Answer (score 2):

So, I love what Travel and the Workplace did with SWAG!

- I'd love a hat that would cover up my baldness, and not [just be virtual](http://lucite.org/lucite/archive/fiction_-_lewis/%28ebook%29%20lewis,%20c.s.%20-%20the%20great%20divorce%20-%20can%20a%20loving%20god%20send%20people%20to%20hell%20-%20%28perfect!%29%28clive,%20cs%20lewis%29%20%28christian%20library%29.pdf).
- I'd love a sticker that would [cover my Mac's nakedness](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3%3A7&version=ESV).
- I'd love some time to finish up my concordance :)
- I'd love a downloadable book, like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004IK8PK0), or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140436324), or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486431851) or even [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061208493)

But mostly, I just want know that everybody is having a good time, wherever we are :)

Comment: Well, we missed the actual anniversary, but we have put together a few swag items. What remains is a method of distribution. ;-)